# GDB quits when running the 'finish' command

Tags: c, gdb, mingw-w64

I downloaded mingw-w64 so I can work on writing programs and debugging them from my home laptop, but for whatever reason, when ever I'm debugging a program with gdb and I wish to exit function using 'finish' command, gdb simply runs until it returns from function and simply exits and I return to the shell's prompt. I have no idea what is causing this bug, and it is especially annoying and make debugging very hard because it forces me to go through every line in a function before exiting (God forbids there's a loop). Has someone encountered this bug before? Is there a solution?

```
PS C:\Users\gamef\OneDrive\Desktop\CPE453\program4_tinyfs> gdb .\a.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from .\a.exe...done.
(gdb) br writeData
Breakpoint 1 at 0x402e44: file TinyFS.c, line 299.
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\Users\gamef\OneDrive\Desktop\CPE453\program4_tinyfs\a.exe
[New Thread 40396.0x1cc8]
[New Thread 40396.0x6e30]
[New Thread 40396.0x3090]
[New Thread 40396.0x9e38]

Thread 1 hit Breakpoint 1, writeData (begBlock=0, data=0x61fab2 "\001_", 'ÿ' <repeats 31 times>, size=254,
    type=DIRECTORY) at TinyFS.c:299
299             Byte buff[BLOCKSIZE] = {0};
(gdb) s
300             buff[MAGIC_OFFSET] = MAGIC_NUMBER;
(gdb) finish
Run till exit from #0  writeData (begBlock=0, data=0x61fab2 "\001_", 'ÿ' <repeats 31 times>, size=254, type=DIRECTORY)
    at TinyFS.c:300
PS C:\Users\gamef\OneDrive\Desktop\CPE453\program4_tinyfs>
```

Comment: Could you post the output from a minimal session too; the version numbers might be relevant too :D

Comment: Sure can. Output added.

Comment: I reverted back to gdb 8.0 and the issue seems to be nonexistent there. So this is only a bug with the 8.1 version

Comment: well, you could add that one as an answer too... seems like it would be useful info for anyone running into the same problem with GDB 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this problem is a caused by a bug inside the 8.1 version of GDB. So I reverted back to GDB 8.0 which seems to work perfectly.

Comment: I had the same problem with gdb 8.1. Now I updated to 8.2.1 and the bug is fixed.